# Apache CXF - WS addressing how to remove/delete ReplyTo from Headers

Tags: cxf, ws-addressing

I'm trying to implement WS-Addressing with Apache CXF 2.7.18. I am able to set some headers like To, Action, etc.. but I want to remove/delete ReplyTo from SOAP request

```
<Action xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">http://...</Action>
<MessageID xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">urn:uuid:....</MessageID>
<To xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">https://....</To>
<ReplyTo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
        <Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</Address>
</ReplyTo>
```

Does anybody know how to do it?

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution even if it's little bit dirty but it works for me. I've explicitly set it to "null" (using Cxf and JaxWsProxyFactoryBean).

```
    EndpointReferenceType replyTo = new EndpointReferenceType();
    AddressingProperties addrProperties = new AddressingProperties();
    AttributedURIType replyToURI = new AttributedURIType();

    EndpointReferenceType from = new EndpointReferenceType();
    AttributedURIType fromURI = new AttributedURIType();
    fromURI.setValue("ms-register");
    from.setAddress(fromURI);
    addrProperties.setFrom(from);
    addrProperties.setFrom(from);

    replyToURI.setValue(null);
    replyTo.setAddress(replyToURI);
    addrProperties.setReplyTo(replyTo);
    client.getRequestContext().put(JAXWSAConstants.CLIENT_ADDRESSING_PROPERTIES,addrPropertie);
```

Comment: What variable is addrProperties?

Comment: AddressingProperties addrProperties = new AddressingProperties(); in which you can set the from addrProperties.setFrom(from)